# Keep hitting API without setInterval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest

I have three pages. Homepage, Chat page and Top navigation page with chat icon. When a user receives new message I want to show a badge with chat icon on the top navigation. For that I'm maintaining a flag in chat model called seen. It's a Boolean. If seen is **false**, I will take a count of the records that is false and show the count in badge with chat icon. For this, I have written a method in top navigations **ngOnit()** to check the chat model if it has any unseen message. I feel it affects the performance because if hit the API every one second. Is there is any better way than **setInterval**.

**Top Navigation TS**

```
ngOnInit()
        {
            setInterval(() => {
               //API Call
                }, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: You could create a websocket connection, this is pretty much the exact usecase it was created for, though your server environment might not support it

Comment: Another thing you could do besides websockets is used exponential backoff to check the API with decreasing frequency. For instance, start by checking every 1 second, then after 10 iterations, increase the poll time to 2 seconds, then 4, 8, and so on up to a reasonable maximum. If a new message is typed/sent/received, reset the interval back to 1 second. This way, the polling is in essentially real time during flurries of conversation, but slightly delayed during idle periods https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff

Comment: Can you give me some reference about how to do it with websocket ?

Comment: You might also consider Server-Sent Events as an alternative to Web Sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hitting the API continuously, you should consider setting up a `websocket` server. You can connect to your server from the `Angular` app to `emit` and `listen` for messages in real time.

---

### Server (websocket on NodeJs)

This is what a simple `websocket` server looks like in `NodeJs`:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8081 });
  
wss.on('connection', ws => {
  onConnection(ws);
  ws.on('message', message => {
    onMessage(message, ws);
  });
  ws.on('error', error => {
    OnError(error);
  });
   ws.on('close', ws=> {
    onClose();
})
});
```

---

### Client (Angular)

In your Angular app, this is what a client side service to handle this connection looks like. Essentially, you create a service that connects to your server, handles `emit` and `subscriptions` - sends new message to a `Subject`. You can return this `Subject` as an `Observable` then subscribe to it in your component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { catchError, tap, switchAll } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EMPTY, Subject } from 'rxjs';
export const WS_ENDPOINT = environment.wsEndpoint;
  
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private socket$: WebSocketSubject<any>;
  private messagesSubject$ = new Subject();
  public messages$ = this.messagesSubject$.pipe(switchAll(), catchError(e => { throw e }));
  
  public connect(): void {
  
    if (!this.socket$ || this.socket$.closed) {
      this.socket$ = this.getNewWebSocket();
      const messages = this.socket$.pipe(
        tap({
          error: error => console.log(error),
        }), catchError(_ => EMPTY));
      this.messagesSubject$.next(messages);
    }
  }
  
  private getNewWebSocket() {
    return webSocket(WS_ENDPOINT);
  }
  sendMessage(msg: any) {
    this.socket$.next(msg);
  }
  close() {
    this.socket$.complete(); }}
```

---

Take a look at this article which describes the workings of a `websocket` server as well as connection from an `Angular` app: https://javascript-conference.com/blog/real-time-in-angular-a-journey-into-websocket-and-rxjs/